# Define a long list of variables in python

Tags: python

I have a long list of variables to define (~100). Define as follows:

```
provider = node.xpath("//provider/text()")[0]
language = node.xpath("//language/text()")[0]
subtype = node.xpath("//subtype/text()")[0]
etc...
```

How would I define it more concisely/DRY, something like -

```
COLUMN_VARIABLES = ['provider', 'language','subtype']

for variable in COLUMN_VARIABLES:
    variable = node.xpath("//%s/text()"%variable)[0]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The more concise way to do this would be to use a dictionary:

```
COLUMN_VARIABLES = ['provider', 'language','subtype']
data = {}

for variable in COLUMN_VARIABLES:
    data[variable] = node.xpath("//%s/text()"%variable)[0]
```

Pro tip: any time you find yourself wanting to use variable variable names, it means you don't want variables, you want one container to hold all that data instead.

Answer (score 3):

Use a *dictionary*:

```
COLUMN_VARIABLES = ['provider', 'language','subtype']

vars = {}    
for variable in COLUMN_VARIABLES:
    vars[variable] = node.xpath("//%s/text()"%variable)[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `dict` to hold the results:

```
column_vars = ['provider', 'language','subtype']
nodes = {}

for var in column_vars:
    nodes[var] = node.xpath("//%s/text()" % variable)[0]
```